# SQL Split Column by Value

Tags: sql

I've searched, and searched, but I'm not even sure what to call this. I'm trying to write an SQL query that splits the data using a key value...

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ Type ║ Data ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║    1 ║ a    ║
║    1 ║ b    ║
║    1 ║ c    ║
║    2 ║ d    ║
║    2 ║ e    ║
║    2 ║ f    ║
║    3 ║ g    ║
║    3 ║ h    ║
║    3 ║ i    ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

To...

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ a ║ d ║ g ║
║ b ║ e ║ h ║
║ c ║ f ║ i ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

What is this called, and how do I do it?

Comment: May be you are looking for whats called "Pivot" in SQL....but it wont accomplish this atleast to my knowledge

Comment: But what happens if you have different cardinalities - if you have 3 group 1, but no group 2 and maybe five group 2?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: If the groups are uneven, I'll drop the rows with the null values. Ultimately, I want to average the rows to one value.

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio 2016.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it's messy.

Ignore the creation of `#Test` since you already have that table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Test

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Results

DECLARE @i AS INTEGER
SET @i = 1

CREATE TABLE #Test
(Type INT
,Data CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(1, 'c'),
(2, 'd'),
(2, 'e'),
(2, 'f'),
(3, 'g'),
(3, 'h'),
(3, 'i')

CREATE TABLE #Results
([1] CHAR(1)
,[2] CHAR(2)
,[3] CHAR(3))

WHILE @i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Test WHERE Type = 1)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO #Results
SELECT
(SELECT TOP 1 Data FROM #Test WHERE Type = 1 AND Data NOT IN (SELECT [1] FROM #Results)) [1]
,(SELECT TOP 1 Data FROM #Test WHERE Type = 2 AND Data NOT IN (SELECT [2] FROM #Results)) [2]
,(SELECT TOP 1 Data FROM #Test WHERE Type = 3 AND Data NOT IN (SELECT [3] FROM #Results)) [3]
FROM #Test

SET @i = @i + 1

END

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #Results
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to create as many ancillary tables as you have groups. So you'll create `table1`, `table2`, and `table3`.

Then you do a `SELECT DISTINCT` of all values in group 1 into `table1`, and so on.

Now you need to stitch these three tables together as columns in a new table. To do so you need another element - a *counter*. Depending on your flavour of SQL, you can do this in several different ways.

In the end you will have three tables of the form

```
Table1        Table2       Table3
id  value     id  value    id value
1   a         1   d        1  f
2   b         2   e        2  g
3   c                      3  h
                           4  i
```

To link these together, you choose the longest one and run `LEFT JOIN`s with the others:

```
SELECT table1.value AS group1, table2.value AS group2, table3.value AS group3 
FROM table3 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table3.id = table2.id)
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table3.id = table1.id);
```

and will get

```
group1    group2   group3
a         d        f
b         e        g
c         NULL     h
NULL      NULL     i
```

You can also do an incremental grouped numbering of all the values in your original table using one additional column:

```
xid    group    value
1      1        a
2      1        b
3      1        c
1      2        d
2      2        e
1      3        f
...
```

Note that (group, xid) is now a primary key. Now you can join your table with itself:

```
 SELECT t1.value AS g1, t2.value AS g2, t3.value AS g3
 FROM yourtable AS t3
 LEFT JOIN yourtable AS t1 ON (t3.xid = t1.xid)
 LEFT JOIN yourtable AS t2 ON (t3.xid = t2.xid)
```

Here, again, group 3 is the one with the largest cardinality. This requires no extra tables, but a slightly more complex numbering of the one extra column `xid` used for stitching the pivot.